# Android Sql Database save encrypted

Tags: android, encryption

I try to save my sql database with a encryption. I use sqlcipher to encrypt my database, but the following code it's not work.

In my activity:

```
    try{
            SqlController.DATABASE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + getString(R.string.app_name) + File.separator + SqlController.DATABASE_NAME;
            controller = new SqlController(this);
            controller.getWritableDatabase(SqlController.DATABASE);
        } catch(Throwable e) {

        }

try{
    ArrayList<Map<Boolean, JSONObject>> list = controller.getUsers();
} catch(Throwable e) { }
```

This is my SqlController class:

```
    import info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase;
import info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import info.guardianproject.database.sqlcipher.SQLiteStatement;

public class SqlController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    public static String DATABASE;

    public SqlController(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE Accs ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Pass TEXT )";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Accs";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }

    public ArrayList<Map<Boolean, JSONObject>> getUsers() {
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: The database is not created, datas are not inserted etc. No errors

Comment: I would start by logging exceptions rather than ignoring them.